# iOS - squish an image vertically

Tags: ios, uiview, layer, uiviewanimation

I have a round image that I want to "squish" vertically so that it looks more like a horizontal line, then expand it back to the original shape. I thought this would work by setting the layer's anchor point to the center and then animating the frame via UIViewAnimation with the height of the frame = 1.

```
[self.imageToSquish.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.imageToSquish.frame.origin.x, self.imageToSquish.frame.origin.y, self.imageToSquish.frame.size.width, 1 );
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                 animations:^{self.imageToSquish.frame = newFrame;}
                 completion:nil];
```

But the image shrinks toward the top instead of around the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re giving it a frame that has its origin—at the top left—in the same position as it started. You probably want to do something more like this, adding half the image’s height:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.imageToSquish.frame.origin.x, self.imageToSquish.frame.origin.y + self.imageToSquish.frame.size.height / 2, self.imageToSquish.frame.size.width, 1);
```

Alternatively—and more efficiently—you could set the image view’s `transform` property to, say, `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.01)` instead of messing with its frame. That’ll be centered on the middle of the image, and you can easily undo it by setting the transform to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.